# Cannot import installed python library yellowbrick to jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, yellowbrick

I installed the yellowbrick python library using pip "install yellowbrick". It was installed, but jupyter notebook cannot import the library. When it imports, results show "No module named 'yellowbrick'". But library had perfectly installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**My experienced the same thing but I tried and it worked by using the following steps :**

1. Open search on your windows
2. Look for anaconda prompt, and click
3. `conda install -c districtdatalabs yellowbrick` (use the following script to install the yellowbrick module)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njdq6.png)

**Where do I get the script from? Here I attach the link:** https://anaconda.org/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick

Answer (score 0):

Use the following on your anaconda prompt or command prompt:

```
conda install yellowbrick
```